# Excel VBA attaching files from SharePoint adding %20 for spaces in filenames

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

Hello we have moved our files to SharePoint and are slowly updating VBA code to reflect the new locations.  One of the VBA code emails files from SharePoint unfortunately the location is now a URL rather than a filepath so it is adding %20 for spaces in filenames. Can anyone assist in keeping spaces in the filenames.  Here is my code

```
Dim OutLookApp As Object
Dim OutLookMailItem As Object
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim MailDest As String
Dim subj As String

LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports (2)").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'change worksheet

For i = 2 To LastRow

    Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    Set OutLookMailItem = OutLookApp.CreateItem(0)
    Set Attach = OutLookMailItem.Attachments

    With OutLookMailItem
    
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "x@x.co.uk"
        .To = "x@x.co.uk"
        '.cc = "x@x.co.uk"
        .Subject = Cells(i, 10).Value
        .body = Cells(i, 11).Value
        Attach.Add Cells(i, 5).Value
        Attach.Add Cells(i, 6).Value
    
    
           .display
          'SendKeys "^{ENTER}"
      
End With
'SendKeys "^{ENTER}"
Next
'Call yes_no_msg
End Sub
```

Comment: `Cells(i, 5).Value` is an HTTP path?

Comment: yes its a file on Sharepoint. the cell contains. 
 =CONCATENATE("https://X.sharepoint.com/sites/YY/ZZZ/MIS_Reports/Daily profits Report_",TEXT($I$1,"ddmmyy"),".xls")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the attachment `DisplayName` to remove `%20` and replace with spaces:

```
Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
With OutLookApp.CreateItem(0)
    .To = "x@x.co.uk"
    .Subject = "subject"
    .Body = "body"
    With .Attachments.Add("https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/XXX/TestLibrary/Code128 Barcodes.xlsm")
        .DisplayName = Replace(.DisplayName, "%20", " ") '<<<<<
    End With
    .Display
End With
```