# Excel VBA adds %20 on filename instead of a space when sending an attachment

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, email-attachments

Long time lurker and always found what I needed, but have to reach out this time.  I found another thread which is the same problem I am having, but no real resolution.  Files are stored on a sharepoint (ugh) and its causing a bit of disruption when sending out emails with attachments that are saved there.  I am receiving %20" embedded into the file names of attachments where there should be a space.

The macro works, email is created and attachment is being added, but this is obviously going to cause errors for the recipients when the file name is not correct.

filename example:
Needed name: Old Dates.xlsx
actual name: Old%20Dates.xlsx

I edited to add FullNameURLEncoded vs FullName as suggested in another other thread, but that did not work.

Any suggestions would be most appreciated!

Here is my code.

```
Dim EmailApp As Outlook.Application
Dim EmailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim fileName As String
 
Set EmailApp = New Outlook.Application
Set EmailItem = EmailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

fileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
'If Not InStr(fileName, ".") > 0 Then
 ' MsgBox "File name does not have the correct format."
  'Exit Sub
'Else
'   fileName = Left(fileName, InStr(fileName, ".") - 30)
'End If
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
With EmailItem
   .To = "michelle@myemail.com"
   .SentOnBehalfOfName = "holley@myemail.com"
   .CC = ""
   .BCC = ""
   .Subject = "Dates"
   .HTMLBody = "Here is this quarters file." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "" & vbNewLine & ""
   .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullNameURLEncoded
   .Display
   Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:00"))
   'Application.SendKeys "%s"
   ActiveWorkbook.Close
    End With`
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Was it [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77152732) question you looked at ?

Comment: `FullNameURLEncoded` will definitely ensure you get %20 instead of space, so it's pushing you in the wrong direction...

Comment: ah!  I'll remove.  I had FullName initially, but it gave the %20 as well.

Comment: No, but that looks more promising than most.  The problem I face is my file  name changes with the input.  It will be Inv  Dates Older Than XX-XX-XX.  Is there a way to enter wildcards here?

Comment: Check the answer posted on this page. It helped me.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77152732/excel-vba-attaching-files-from-sharepoint-adding-20-for-spaces-in-filenames/77152861#77152861?newreg=bf169c42e3884a2fafc2eee246711731